# How to decrypt AES-GCM encrypted text with password and javascript function?

Tags: javascript, aes, aes-gcm

```js
async function generateAESKeyFromPassword(password) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const passwordKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey('raw',encoder.encode(password),'PBKDF2', false,['deriveKey']);
  return await crypto.subtle.deriveKey({
    name: 'PBKDF2',
    salt: crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16)),
    iterations: 100000,
    hash: 'SHA-256',
  }, passwordKey, {
    name: 'AES-GCM',
    length: 256,
  }, true, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);
}

async function encryptText(password, plaintext) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const data = encoder.encode(plaintext);
    const key = await generateAESKeyFromPassword(password);

    const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
    const ciphertext = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
      {
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        iv: iv,
      },
      key,
      data
    );
    
    const combined = new Uint8Array(12 + ciphertext.byteLength);
    combined.set(iv);
    combined.set(new Uint8Array(ciphertext), 12);
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...combined));
}

async function decryptText(key, combinedBase64) {
    const combinedArray = new Uint8Array(
      atob(combinedBase64)
        .split('')
        .map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0))
    );
    
    const iv = combinedArray.slice(0, 12);
    const ciphertextArray = combinedArray.slice(12);
    
    const decryptedData = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      {
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        iv: iv,
      },
      key,
      ciphertextArray
    );
    
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    const decryptedText = decoder.decode(decryptedData);
    
    return decryptedText;
}

const encryptedTextBase64 = "Jkf7KDJjnxwYapwGyiaVltQyIdw5whGrKSAo2qeLqYNd8aXwMeIzsFRkz4Z4yZlNfhKw+moqnST6xOuK8lR41vPAhKuv0jfWtmGwmGZGIRIDFxJSCZCElvfANw==";
const password = "mypassword";

generateAESKeyFromPassword(password)
  .then(key => {
    return decryptText(key, encryptedTextBase64);
  })
  .then(decryptedText => {
    console.log("SUCCESS:", decryptedText);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("ERROR:", error);
  });
```

Cipher: Jkf7KDJjnxwYapwGyiaVltQyIdw5whGrKSAo2qeLqYNd8aXwMeIzsFRkz4Z4yZlNfhKw+moqnST6xOuK8lR41vPAhKuv0jfWtmGwmGZGZGIRIDFxJSCZCElvfANw==
password: "mypassword".
iv is in cipher.

I can only assume that the problem is with the new AESKEY generation (function generateAESKeyFromPassword) and intuitively I assume that I shouldn't generate it, but how do I decrypt then?

Comment: The salt used in `generateAESKeyFromPassword()` is not stored anywhere, so different salts are used during encryption and decryption, hence different keys are generated, which is why decryption fails. The correct way is to concatenate the salt generated during encryption with the ciphertext (analogous to IV) so that it is available during decryption.

Comment: Also, there are some edge cases when using `atob` and `btoa`,  not sure if could affect anything here, but MDN has some good info on it here ->  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64

Answer (score 0):

```js
const encryptForm = document.getElementById("encrypt");
encryptForm.addEventListener("submit", async function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const dataText = this.querySelector(".text").value;
  const dataPassword = this.querySelector(".password").value;
  const resultBlock = this.querySelector(".result");
  
  const encryptedData = await encryptText(dataPassword, dataText);
  
  resultBlock.innerHTML = "result: " + encryptedData;
});

const decryptForm = document.getElementById("decrypt");
decryptForm.addEventListener("submit", async function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const dataText = this.querySelector(".text").value;
  const dataPassword = this.querySelector(".password").value;
  const resultBlock = this.querySelector(".result");
  
  const decryptedData = await decryptText(dataPassword, dataText);
  
  resultBlock.innerHTML = "result: " + decryptedData;
});

async function genAES(password, salt) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const passwordEncoded = encoder.encode(password);

  const passwordKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    passwordEncoded,
    "PBKDF2",
    false,
    ["deriveKey"]
  );

  return await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
    {
      name: "PBKDF2",
      salt: salt,
      iterations: 1,
      hash: "SHA-256"
    },
    passwordKey,
    {
      name: "AES-GCM",
      length: 256
    },
    true,
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
  );
}

async function encryptText(password, plaintext) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const data = encoder.encode(plaintext);
  const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
  const salt = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
  const key = await genAES(password, salt);

  const ciphertext = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
      name: "AES-GCM",
      iv: iv
    },
    key,
    data
  );

  // Объединение salt, iv и ciphertext в одном ArrayBuffer
  const combined = new Uint8Array(16 + 12 + ciphertext.byteLength);
  combined.set(salt);
  combined.set(iv, 16);
  combined.set(new Uint8Array(ciphertext), 16 + 12);

  return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...combined));
}

async function decryptText(password, enrcyptdata) {
  const combinedArray = new Uint8Array(
    atob(enrcyptdata)
      .split('')
      .map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0))
  );

  const salt = combinedArray.slice(0, 16);
  const iv = combinedArray.slice(16, 28);
  const ciphertextArray = combinedArray.slice(28);
  const key = await genAES(password, salt);
  
  const decryptedData = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
    {
      name: 'AES-GCM',
      iv: iv,
    },
    key,
    ciphertextArray
  );

  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  const decryptedText = decoder.decode(decryptedData);

  return decryptedText;
}
```

```html
<form id="encrypt">
  <h1>Encrypt</h1>
  <p>text</p>
  <input type="text" class="text">
  <p>password</p>
  <input type="text" class="password">
  <p><button>Encrypt</button> <span class="result"></span></p>
</form>

<form id="decrypt">
  <h1>Decrypt</h1>
  <p>encrypt data</p>
  <input type="text" class="text">
  <p>password</p>
  <input type="text" class="password">
  <p><button>Decrypt</button> <span class="result"></span></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).